# Override accessor in Java

Tags: java, accessor

Is there any way to override the default accessor for a property of an object in Java?

For example if I call Foo.bar, is there some way to know when the bar property is accessed without using a getter function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by, `"without using a getter function"`? If you extend Foo and ***override*** bar's getter method, and if bar is private, then yes you can find out when it is accessed.

This is one reason why properties ***should*** all be private, so that you the programmer have full control over what is seen, by whom, and what can change.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it without using a getter as one can do in other languages like Ruby. Clearly there isn't though :(

Comment: @nyx: no, there isn't. Each language has its own way, its own path for solving problems, and this is the way of Java.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that was the most insightful comment I have ever seen anywhere...

Comment: @nyx Java is not nearly as dynamic as ruby and python, but this translates into better runtime performance because a property access does not have the overhead of a function call. The JVM also optimizes away simple getters/setters to have no function call overhead.

Comment: @AnubianNoob: thank you. I'm a zen master (not). And 1+ to your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you all for your insight and prompt responses!

Answer (score 4):

No. Foo should be written like this:

```
private [type] bar;
public [type] getBar() { return bar; }
```

This allows you to do things when bar is accessed. If bar is public, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question,

> For example if I call Foo.bar, is there some way to know when the bar property is accessed without using a getter function?

Think about this question.  A getter will allow you to add this functionality.  If the property is private, this problem goes away as any caller is required to use the appropriate getter call.  This is an entrenched Java Bean standard.

It's possible to weave aspects into your code to intercept field access, using Aspect Oriented programming (AOP: AspectJ, for example), however there are caveats to this solution which is beyond the scope of your question, but happy to answer in another one :-)